# Updating multiple subfields of a field using ekmett’s Lens

Tags: haskell, lenses

*Let’s play a game.* There are two piles we’re going to use, both consisting of black/white sided chips.

```
data Pile = Pile { _blacks, _whites :: Int }
makeLenses ''Pile

data Game = Game { _pileA, _pileB :: Pile }
makeLenses ''Game
```

A really clever move would be to turn over a black chip in pile A, and a white chip — in pile B. But how?

```
cleverMove :: Game -> Game
cleverMove game = game & pileA . blacks -~ 1
                       & pileA . whites +~ 1
                       & pileB . blacks +~ 1
                       & pileB . whites -~ 1
```

Not very elegant. How can I do it without referencing each pile twice?

The only thing I came up with (and I don’t like it):

```
cleverMove game = game & pileA %~ (blacks -~ 1)
                                . (whites +~ 1)
                       & pileB %~ (blacks +~ 1)
                                . (whites -~ 1)
```

(Sorry in advance if it’s obvious — I’m kinda new to lenses and I feel lost in the sea of combinators and operators `lens` offers. There’s probably everything for everybody’s needs hiding there. Not that it’s bad, of course! but I wish there was also a complete manual included.)

Comment: What do you not like about option 2? It can't get much more concise than that, can it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don’t like that I had to use brackets, which become clumsy when there are multiline expressions involved — such as `do` blocks and further levels of nesting.

Comment: I think it would help if you showed some rough pseudo-code corresponding to what your ideal syntax would look like.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez My ideal syntax is the same as my “non-ideal” syntax, except without brackets. The thing is, I want to know the idiomatic solution, if there is one (and since updating multiple subfields should be a rather common task, I’d be surprised to know that there *isn’t* one).

Comment: If the individual updates start to consume multiple lines, it is probably time to step back, start a `let` or `where` block, and start naming things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `Traversal` is a generalization of `Lens` which "focuses" on multiple values. Think of it like `traverse` which allows you to step through a `Traversable t` modifying values in an `Applicative` (`traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)` looks pretty much like the type of a `Lens` already, you'll notice—just think of `t b ~ whole`).

For a `Traversal` we can just pick off the values we want to change. For instance, let me generalize your `Pile` a bit and built a `Traversal`.

```
data Pile = Pile { _blacks :: Int, _whites :: Int, _name :: String } deriving (Show)
$(makeLenses ''Pile)

counts :: Traversal' Pile Int
counts f (Pile blacks whites name) = 
  Pile <$> f blacks <*> f whites <*> pure name
```

so as you can see, I visit both the `blacks` and the `whites` with `f` but leave `name` `pure`. This is almost the same way you write a `Traversable` instance except you always visit *all* of the (homogenous) elements contained in the `Traversable` structure.

```
Main*> Pile 0 0 "test" & counts +~ 1
Pile {_blacks = 1, _whites = 1, _name = "test"}
```

This isn't enough to do what you want, though, since you need to update your fields in *different* ways. For that, you need to specify your logic and ensure it upholds an entirely different set of rules.

```
blackToWhite :: Pile -> Pile
blackToWhite = (blacks -~ 1) . (whites +~ 1)
```